# Get log in credentials from web.config in javascript for ajax request asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to get log in credentials from a web.config file, and then use it in jquery .ajax method? Basically, for this scenario I cannot use code behind to accomplish this.

Second - if I am able to get the credentials, how do I use them in .ajax? If the username is 'Joe' and the password '1234', and the URL /mytest.aspx, would it look something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/mytest.aspx',
    type: 'get',
    data: -- would log in info go here? --,
    success: function(data) {
               alert(xhr.statuscode);
             }
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible to get log in credentials from a
>   web.config file, and then use it in jquery .ajax method? Basically,
>   for this scenario I cannot use code behind to accomplish this.

Absolutely not, only server side code can access web.config.  Javascript runs client side, and web.config is not accessible from the client.  You would either need to include the web.config values in the page as it's rendered such as in hidden fields(thus your javascript could retrieve the values from the hidden fields), or have create a web service method that will allow you to retrieve the values via an ajax call.

> Second - if I am able to get the credentials, how do I use them in
>   .ajax? If the username is 'Joe' and the password '1234', and the URL
>   /mytest.aspx, would it look something like this:

This is using an json object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mytest.aspx',
    type: 'get',
    data: { username: usernameVar , email: emailVar },
    success: function(data) {
               alert(xhr.statuscode);
             }
});
```

Assumes you have declared a usernameVar and emailVar holding the values you wish to submit in the ajax call.  Obviously add whatever properties of the credentials you want to pass, I have shown username and email.  If you are passing password then you should ensure you have an encrypted connection, i.e. SSL and `https` as the protocol on the ajax url.

Note that the client, whoever the user is on this webpage, will be able to get these credentials(it's easy to inspect the webpage's hidden fields or the ajax request).  So basically it reveals the username and password in your web.config to **all** of your users.  I have a strong feeling what you are trying to do is very bad.

It might be advantageous to ask a new question that covers more of what your intentions are and why you are trying to do what you are asking.

Comment: This covers all that I needed. I was thinking of using hidden fields too. Thanks for the help.